# Showing loader gif in datatables

Tags: datatable, datatables

I'm using datatables. My code is working fine. Now I want to add a loader image(gif). I don't know how to add this. Here is my datatable script .

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ref = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax": "mails",
        "columns": [
                    { "data": "from" },
                    { "data": "object" },
                    { "data": "created" }
                ]
    } );

} );
```

Comment: Do you want to replace the default process text of DataTable to an image loader or do you want to show your custom loader? As you have set `"processing": true`, you must be seeing the `Processing...` text..right?

Comment: Yes ..i want to replace Processing... by Gif image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply put an image tag within the language option:

```
language: {
          processing: "<img src='img/loading.gif'>"
      }
```

Comment: **Note** that `language.processing` is shown [when the table is processing a user action (like sorting)](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.processing) while `language.loadingRecords` is shown [when an AJAX sourced client based table is loading records](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.loadingRecords).

Answer (score 5):

You can use `language.sLoadingRecords` to show an ajaxload-gif, example :

```js
...
language : {
  sLoadingRecords : '<span style="width:100%;"><img src="http://www.snacklocal.com/images/ajaxload.gif"></span>'
},  
...
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/acjngj30/**