# Changing DataTables Ajax Source default string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'm using jquery DataTables 1.10 with Ajax sourced data and would like to change the default string "Loading" to a gif. I did some research but to no success, i found some suggestions online which were:

```
<script>
    oLanguage: {
        sProcessing: "<img src='loading.gif'>"
    },
    processing: true
</script>
<script>
    "language": {
        "processing": "This is a Test"
    },
    processing: true
</script>
```

But neither of the two suggestions worked, what am i doing wrong, would appreciate your assistance thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Showing loader gif in datatables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33671317/showing-loader-gif-in-datatables) - as you see in the mentioned link you should use `sLoadingRecords` not `sProcessing`.

Comment: Thanks alot i think that should work.